# how to grab the values from json

Tags: jquery, json

I have some jquery/ajax which returns some JSON with two values.  I do not know how to put those two values into variables to use in output.  Or perhaps I can use them without moving them to variables?

jquery ajax statement:

```
$.ajax({
                                url: "proposemarriage_backend.php",
                                type: 'POST',
                                datatype: 'json',
                                data: 'wedding=' + firstweddingturn,

                                    success: function(result) {
                                        alert(result);
                                    }
                                }); // end ajax
```

PHP backend:

```
$wedding1 = mysql_real_escape_string(filter_input(INPUT_POST,'wedding'));
if ($wedding1 > '0') {
list($season) = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT season FROM calendar WHERE calendar_ID=$wedding1",$db));
list($year) = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT year FROM calendar WHERE calendar_ID=$wedding1",$db));

$resultarray = array();

$resultarray[] = $season;
$resultarray[] = $year;

$resultjson = json_encode($resultarray);
echo $resultjson;
```

I end up with a result like "Early Spring", "71".  And I want to do something like:

```
$('#div1').append('<br>The returned season is ' + season + ' and the year is ' + year + '.</br>')
```

Comment: For the next question: the code you use to generate your JSON is absolutely irrelevant if your question is how to read it from JavaScript. What you need to show is the JSON itself and `"Early Spring", "71"` cannot be the real JSON (to begin with, it's not even valid JSON).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first entries:

```
$('#div1').append('<br>The returned season is ' + result[0] + ' and the year is ' + result[1] + '.</br>');
```

Loop to get the rest. Ideally, though, you should change the PHP to put the seasons in `result[0][]` and the years in `result[1][]`. Or better yet, `result['seasons']` and `result['years']`.

EDIT:
You've got a typo. Change `datatype` to `dataType`. Once this is done, jQuery will automatically parse the JSON string to the right object structure.

Comment: Hm, result[0] gives me [, result[1] gives ", result [2] gives E.  It seems that each has a single character.   I tried doing result["season"] from PHP, with no luck.

Comment: @jeremy: Yeah, you've not *defined* `result['season']` so you'll not get anything. Please post the JSON string and let us take a look. Right now the javascript `result` contains a JSON string. You'll need to parse it to turn it into an object.

Comment: as given from alert(result), it is ["Early Spring"],["71"].  or if I modify my PHP, it returns {"season":"Early Spring","year":"71"}   Its worth noting that this would only ever be returning two values.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#div1').append('<br>The returned season is ' + result[0] + ' and the year is ' + result[1] + '.</br>')
```